# Sorting by a virtual attribute in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activerecord

**BACKGROUND:** I have a set of Posts that can be voted on. I'd like to sort Posts according to their "vote score" which is determined by the following equation:

( (@post.votes.count) / ( (Time.now - @post.created_at) ** 1 ) )

I am currently defining the vote score as such:

```
  def vote_score(x)
   ( (x.votes.count) / ( (Time.now - x.created_at) ** 1 ) )
  end
```

And sorting them as such:

```
@posts = @posts.sort! { |a,b| vote_score((b) <=> vote_score((a) }
```

**OBJECTIVE:** This method takes a tremendous toll on my apps load times. Is there a better, more efficient way to accomplish this kind of sorting?

Comment: Is there a reason you're raising your equation to the power of 1?  That seems unnecessary.

Comment: You also have 2 extra `(` in the last code you posted.

Comment: you are both right, i've been playing around with the values and at the time of posting the power happened to be 1 - no particular reason. same with the brackets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you can do the entire thing using a query:

```
SELECT   posts.id,
         (COUNT(votes.id)/(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC(posts.created_at))) as score
FROM     posts INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Or:

```
class Post
  scope :with_score, select('posts.*')
    .select('(COUNT(votes.id)/(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC(posts.created_at))) as score')
    .joins(:votes)
    .group('posts.id')
    .order('score DESC')
end
```

Which would make your entire query:

```
@posts = Post.with_score.all
```

P.S: You can then modify your Post class to use the SQL version of score if it is present. You can also make the score function cached in an instance so you don't have to re-calculate it every time you ask for a post's score:

```
class Post
  def score
    @score ||= self[:score] || (votes.count/(Time.now.utc - x.created_at.utc)
  end
end
```

P.S: The SQLLite3 equivalent is:

```
strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',posts.created_at)
```

Comment: +1 for realizing that writing SQL is faster, better, and smarter than using built-in Ruby functions :)

Comment: In trying this out I am shown this error: "SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: TIME_TO_SEC: SELECT  posts.*,..."

Comment: In sqllite3 you want to use strftime('%s','now'), where 'now' means the current time or can be replaced with the time you want to compute seconds for, instead of the TIME_TO_SEC function which is for MySQL.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of sqlite mastery, getting this now:

"syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('...votes.id)/(strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s','post..."   

error is pointing to the comma in the first strftime...

Comment: Check my answer. You should use strftime('%s',posts.created_at) not strftime('%s','posts.created_at').

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't use `sort!` if you are going to assign to the same variable (it is wrong in this case), you should change the sort to:

   ```
   @posts.sort!{|a, b| vote_score(b) <=> vote_score(a) }
   ```
2. It looks like you are counting the votes for Post each time you call another Post which is hitting the database quite a bit and probably the source of the toll on your load times, you can use a `counter_cache` to count each time a vote is made and store that in the posts table.  This will make it so you only do one db query to load from the posts table.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html