# Rails how to order after an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my konkurrancerstable I have:

```
rating_score => The current score (integer)
ratings => The number of ratings which led to the score (integer)
```

In my view I want to sort konkurrancers after rating.
So I have to do this math: rating_score/ratings
ratings may not be null because I can not divide be zero.

```
<% @konkurrencer.find(:all, :order => '@rating ASC', :limit => 5).each do |vind| %>
  <%= link_to(image_tag(vind.banner2, :style => 'border:none; width:125px; height:125px;'), vind.tracking, :target => '_blank')  %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index 
    @konkurrencer = Konkurrancer
  end
end
```

My view:

```
15: <%= @konkurrencer.find(:all, :select => "rating_score/ratings AS rating", :order => 'rating ASC', :limit => 5).each do |da| %>
16: <%= da.banner2 %>
17: <% end %>
```

And I get following error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Public#index Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/public/_konkurrencer.html.erb where line #16 raised: missing attribute: banner2
```

How do I create the instance variable rating to order the konkurrancers?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292624/sorting-by-a-virtual-attribute-in-rails-3) help?

Comment: Do you mean "instance variable", not "instant variable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing else, you can sort your list of records by two criteria *after* retrieving them from the database.

In the `index` method in your controller, I'd do this:

```
@konkurrancers = Konkurrancer.find(:all, :order => '@rating ASC')
@konkurrancers.sort! {|a, b|
  rel = a.rating_score <=> b.rating_score
  # if "rating_scores" are equivalent, only then consider "ratings"
  rel == 0 ? a.ratings <=> b.ratings : rel
}
```

That much will give you a list of all your Konkurrencer objects, sorted by two criteria.

In your view, I'd do this:

```
<% @konkurrancers[0,5].each do |vind| %>
   <%= link_to(image_tag(vind.banner2, :style => 'border:none; width:125px; height:125px;'), vind.tracking, :target => '_blank')  %>
<% end %
```

That should create the html for only the first 5 items in the list you made in your controller. (Is that what you wanted?)

Comment: NoMethodError in PublicController#index

undefined method `sort!' for #<Class:0x5f8b360>

Comment: Put it in the controller.  As for the error message you got, make sure you're applying the `sort!` method to a list of objects: `@koncurrancer.find(...).sort! {...}` should do it.

Comment: I have used you the code above and i get the following error: NameError in PublicController#index

uninitialized constant PublicController::Konkurrencer

Comment: Can you tell me the name of your Model and/or table (from which your ratings are being drawn)?  Is it Konkurrencer or Konkurrancer?

Comment: The model is Konkurrancer and the table konkurrancers

Comment: My mistake, then.  I intially wrote `Konkurrencer.find`; you need `Konkurrancer.find` (1st line after `def index`).  (I've fixed the code I wrote above.)

Comment: Thank you I have a textfield that I want to set the valute to the current rating. I have tried this but it gives a error :value => '<% if vind.ratings == 0 %>0<% else %><%= vind.rating_score/vind.ratings %><% end %>'

Comment: Where you enter your value, you're already writing in ruby (the `:value =>` is ruby), so you don't need to put the `<% %>` around what follows (if you've got the `<% %>` surrounding the larger statement).  Does the entire line of code go something like `<% text_field_tag ... :value => ... %>`?

Comment: Alas, I've run short of time, so I'll have to look at this another day.  Is it showing 5 of the non-highest-rated konkurrancers?  If so, can you piece together some attribute about them that stands out (e.g. highest/lowest `rating_score` or highest/lowest `ratings`)?

Comment: The rating is rating_score/ratings. I want to show the 5 konkurrancers with the highest rating.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the konkurrancers are being sorted by `rating_score` divided-by `ratings`.  So your list is showing the 5 instances with the highest `rating_score/ratings`.  But it _should_ show the five with the highest `rating_score`. Is that the case?  (If so, would you try removing the `.sort!` command in the controller? What results do you get then?)

Comment: I want to show the five konkurrancers with the highest rating(rating_score/ratings)

Comment: If I understand you now, then you want to change the `.sort! {...}` instructions I gave earlier to `.sort! {|a,b| a.rating_score/a.ratings <=> b.rating_score/b.ratings}` (just one line now, not two).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL you can use

```
@konkurrencer.find(:all, :select => "rating_score/ratings AS rating", :order => 'rating ASC', :limit => 5)

class Konkurrencer
  def rating
    self[:rating] || (rating_score/rating)
  end
end
```

rshallit linked to a good post about this above. However it is in Rails 3 and it appears you are using Rails < 3

Comment: I get a this error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Public#index

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/public/_konkurrencer.html.erb where line #16 raised:

missing attribute: banner2

Comment: How is it done in Mysql I use it on my local pc and SQL on my server

Comment: The select clause in the find method needs to include all the fields you need. I.e. :select => "banner2, rating_score/ratings AS rating" etc